# extract node from xml in db2

Tags: db2, extract

i 'm struggling how to extract a node from an xml that has multiple nodes
this is the xml

```
<DataArea>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>aaa</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>bbb</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
<TB001I>
<IOCOD>ccc</IOCOD>
<IODESC>desc</IODESC>
</TB001I>
</DataArea>
```

this is the SP that i'm trying to create

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTSQL 
( 
  IN  inpdoc  XML, 
  OUT p2      VARCHAR(30), 
  OUT p3      VARCHAR(30) 
) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
BEGIN 
declare i int; 
declare z int; 
declare p4 varchar(30); 
set i = 0; 
set z = 1; 
while (z = 1) do 
   set i = i + 1; 
  SET p2 = 
        XMLCAST 
        ( 
          XMLQUERY('$d/DataArea/TB001[1]/cdcod' PASSING inpdoc AS "d") 
          AS VARCHAR(30) 
        ); 

  SET p3 =XMLCAST 
    ( XMLQUERY('$d/DataArea/TB001[i]/ccdesc' PASSING inpdoc AS "d") 
       AS VARCHAR(30) 
    ); 
  SET p4 = 
    XMLCAST 
    ( 
      XMLQUERY('$d/DataArea/TB001[last()]/cdcod' PASSING inpdoc AS "d") 
      AS VARCHAR(30) 
    ); 
 SET p5 = 

      XMLQUERY('for $b in$d/DataArea/TB001 return $b/cdcod' PASSING inpdoc        AS "d"); 
   if i = 5 then 
       set z = 0; 
   end if; 
end while; 

END
```

when i run the SP, P2 and P4 are ok but P3 doesn't return anything
i would have a node for any tag of type TB001I or looping in the xml and get back any values for IOCOD and IODESC

can you help on this?
thank you

Comment: the xmlquery is wrong but also with the correct one that is $d/DataArea/TB001I[i]/IOCOD doesn't work

Comment: There's a lot wrong with the code you've posted. The element names in your XML are `IOCOD` and `IODESC`, but your XQuery is referencing `cdcode` and `ccdesc`. Variable `p5` isn't declared anywhere in your stored procedure. Since you say you're able to run the procedure and get partially correct results, please edit your question so the code it contains is valid.

Comment: Aside from the other issues, your procedure is currently written to iterate until `i` is equal to five, overwriting `p3` every time with whatever is in `//TB001[i]/ccdesc`, even when nothing exists at that position in the document. Hard-coding five iterations into your loop (regardless of size of your `inpdoc` input document) means that at the end of the loop, `p3` will always be empty whenever the input document contains fewer than five `//TB001` elements.